# Pyspark - Error closing multipart upload - Task failed while writing rows. - java.util.concurrent.CancellationException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

My application, read S3 parquet data in parquet format and partitions the data. I have written a custom partitioner to equally redistribute the data.

my code looks something like this

```
        df = spark.read.parquet("{}".format(args.s3location))
        df_join --> I join here to actually DF to add salting columns. For simplicty i removed the code here

        df_join.repartition(8000, F.col("col1"),
                           F.col("col2"), F.col("col3"), F.col("salting_column")) \
            .write.partitionBy("col1"), "col2", "col3") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .format("parquet") \
            .save("{}".format(args.outputlocation)
```

The size input data is around 10TB, This program runs successfuly and writes the data in desired format. Except there are multiple failed tasks  with below error, out of 8000 tasks i am noticing somewhere around 100-150 tasks are being failed, just want to make sure that i am missing something obvious.

```
19/12/25 18:21:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4012.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 175242)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error closing multipart upload
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.doMultiPartUpload(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:441)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.close(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopPositionOutputStream.close(HadoopPositionOutputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:685)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:122)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionDataWriter.write(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadMultiParts(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:382)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.doMultiPartUpload(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:434)
    ... 25 more
```